# Pass Non-Static Member without externally setting it

Tags: c++, winapi, static-members

I have two classes defined as:

```
class Control
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> Info;

    public:
        Control(..);
        virtual ~Control();
        LRESULT __stdcall SubClass(HWND Window, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
};

class Button: public Control
{
    //...
};


Control::Control(..)
{
    SetWindowSubclass(..., SubClass, ...); //Need to pass member function as callback..
}

LRESULT __stdcall Control::SubClass(HWND Window, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    //Use "Info" data member in here.. thus I cannot have static callback in order to use it.
}
```

And so I came up with:

```
class Control
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> Info;
        static LRESULT __stdcall SetCallback(void* ThisPtr) {return static_cast<Control*>(ThisPtr)->SubClass;};

    public:
        //all the same stuff..
};

Control::Control(..)
{
    SetWindowSubclass(..., SetCallback, ...);
}
```

But the above throws a whole bunch of errors. Is there anyway to either have my static callback access other datamembers OR have my callback non-static?
I do not want to have to do something like the following for every instance created (which I've seen as suggestions all over the internet):

```
Control F;
F.SetCallback(&F::SubClass, &F); //Externally sets member as callback which I don't want.
```

I'm trying to keep everything in the constructor or the class itself.

Comment: oh well i guess it's time to "publish" an example here on SO. your hunch that it's a good idea to all the creating in the constructor, C++ RAII, is a good one. but unfortunately current c++ gui frameworks generally don't do that. the only ones i know that do it are my own mostly unpublished bits-and-pieces work (I did publish full source code to a "screensaver manager") and John Torjo's [win32gui library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32gui/), which he wrote a series of articles about (not sure which of us did this first). ok lemme code something up. first some coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most common question when it comes to Win32 API UI programming. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381400(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically the trick is to call SetWindowLongPtr with GWLP_USERDATA as the first parameter and **this** as the second. Then in the WindowProc callback use GetWindowLongPtr to get it from the HWND.

Comment: Very nice! But this only works for WM_CREATE and thus it cannot be used in Subclassing. =( I still bookmarked it though as it is very very useful!

Comment: You don't need to use `SetWindowLongPtr()` if you use `SetWindowSubclass()`.  The fourth parameter allows you to pass user-defined data to the callback.  That can be your `this` pointer.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames That's what virtual methods are for. Declare virtual methods in the Control class (such methods are usually named OnRender, OnMouseLeftButtonDown, etc) and then override them as needed in the subclasses.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I tried that and when accessing datamembers through it, it will throw an exception or give invalid data. :l

-user1610015 subclass in this case is referring to subclassing a window. Not a child class.

Comment: Ahh figured it out.. I was creating a stack object instead of a heap object and it was being deleted so it was accessing invalid data.. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how to pass calls to the freestanding message handler function, on to a member function of your C++ object.

It's a lot of code, but normally you would abstract this away in some reusable module, and the most basic stuff is just the little class **`gui::api_level::window_subclasser_t`**.

I haven't shown very much error handling, and neither does this code support programmatic destruction of the C++ object via external `delete` (I think the sane way to do this is to just `DestroyWindow` the API level window and let that propagate up to self-destruction of the C++ object, but it's many years since last time I did this).

```
#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#undef  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
//#include <windowsx.h>
#include <commctrl.h>   // SetWindowSubclass

#include <assert.h>     // assert
#include <stdexcept>    // std::exception, std::runtime_error
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string>       // std::string

#ifndef IS_DELETED
#   define  IS_DELETED      = delete            // C++11
#endif

namespace cpp {
    using namespace std;

    bool hopefully( bool condition ) { return condition; }
    bool throw_x( string const& s ) { throw runtime_error( s ); }
}  // namespace cpp

namespace winapi {
    using cpp::hopefully;
    using cpp::throw_x;

    bool get( MSG& m )
    {
        int const code = ::GetMessage( &m, 0, 0, 0 );
        hopefully( code >= 0 )
            || throw_x( "winapi::get( MSG ): GetMessage failed" );
        return !!code;
    }
}  // namespace winapi

namespace gui {
    using cpp::hopefully;
    using cpp::throw_x;

    namespace api_level
    {
        class message_handler_t
        {
        public:
            virtual LRESULT window_proc( MSG const& message ) = 0;
        };

        LRESULT CALLBACK main_window_subclassproc(
            HWND const      window,
            UINT const      message_id,
            WPARAM const    w_param,
            LPARAM const    l_param,
            UINT_PTR const  subclass_id,
            DWORD_PTR const data
            )
        {
            (void) subclass_id; struct subclass_id;

            auto const p_handler = reinterpret_cast< message_handler_t* >( data );
            MSG const message = { window, message_id, w_param, l_param, DWORD(), POINT() };
            return p_handler->window_proc( message );
        }

        class window_subclasser_t
        {
        private:
            enum { subclass_id = 1 };

            HWND    window_handle_;

            window_subclasser_t( window_subclasser_t const& ) IS_DELETED;
            window_subclasser_t& operator=( window_subclasser_t const& ) IS_DELETED;

        public:
            HWND handle() const { return window_handle_; }

            LRESULT pass_to_superclass( MSG const& m )
            {
                return ::DefSubclassProc( m.hwnd, m.message, m.wParam, m.lParam );
            }

            ~window_subclasser_t()
            {
                ::RemoveWindowSubclass(
                    window_handle_,
                    &main_window_subclassproc,
                    subclass_id
                    )
                    || throw_x( "gui::api_level::window_subclass_t::<destroy>(): RemoveWindowSubclass failed" );
            }

            window_subclasser_t(
                HWND const          api_window,
                message_handler_t*  cpp_window
                )
                : window_handle_( api_window )
            {
                assert( cpp_window != 0 );
                ::SetWindowSubclass(
                    window_handle_,
                    main_window_subclassproc,
                    subclass_id,
                    reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>( cpp_window )
                    )
                    || throw_x( "gui::api_level::window_subclass_t::<init>(): SetWindowSubclass failed" );
            }
        };

        ATOM create_main_window_class()
        {
            WNDCLASS params = {};
            params.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
            params.hCursor = ::LoadCursor( 0, IDC_ARROW );
            params.hIcon = ::LoadIcon( 0, IDI_APPLICATION );
            params.hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
            params.lpfnWndProc = &::DefWindowProc;
            params.lpszClassName = L"MainWindow";
            ATOM const result = ::RegisterClass( &params );
            hopefully( result != 0 )
                || throw_x( "gui::api_level::create_main_window_class: RegisterClass failed" );
            return result;
        }

        ATOM main_window_class()
        {
            static ATOM const the_class = create_main_window_class();
            return the_class;
        }

        HWND create_main_window()
        {
            HWND const window = ::CreateWindow(
                MAKEINTATOM( main_window_class() ),
                L"My main window",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                400, 300,
                HWND(),             // Parent.
                HMENU(),            // Menu.
                ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr ),
                nullptr             // Param.
                );
            hopefully( window != 0 )
                || throw_x( "gui::api_level::create_main_window: CreateWindow failed" );
            return window;
        }
    }  // api_level

    class window_t
        : private api_level::message_handler_t
    {
    private:
        window_t( window_t const& ) IS_DELETED;
        window_t& operator=( window_t const& ) IS_DELETED;

        api_level::window_subclasser_t  subclasser_;

        virtual LRESULT window_proc( MSG const& m ) override
        {
            switch( m.message )
            {
            case WM_DESTROY:
                delete this;
                ::PostQuitMessage( 0 );
                return 0;
            default:
                return subclasser_.pass_to_superclass( m );
            }
        }

    protected:
        struct api_object_factory_t
        {
            virtual HWND create() const
            {
                return api_level::create_main_window();
            }
        };

        virtual ~window_t() {}

        window_t( api_object_factory_t const& factory )
            : subclasser_( factory.create(), this )
        {}

    public:
        HWND handle() const { return subclasser_.handle(); }
        void show() { ::ShowWindow( handle(), SW_SHOW ); }
    };
}  // namespage gui


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                               Usage:

class main_window_t
    : public gui::window_t
{
public:
    main_window_t()
        : gui::window_t( api_object_factory_t() )
    {}
};

void cpp_main()
{
    auto const main_window = new main_window_t();
    main_window->show();
    MSG msg;
    while( winapi::get( msg ) )
    {
        ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
        ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
    assert( msg.message == WM_QUIT );
}

#include <iostream>
auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    try                         { cpp_main();  return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
    catch( exception const& x ) { wcerr << "!" << x.what() << endl; }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

To compile this with Visual C++ 11.0, define the preprocessor symbol `IS_DELETED` as nothing.