# What is the typical convention for organization with Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, organization

I've been working a lot with Win32 lately, but I'm pretty new to it, and need some advice concerning organization.  In C++, although it works syntactically to declare global variables, I was always under the impression that this was sloppy, because the variable can then be modified anywhere, so it becomes much more difficult to track changes to it.

In my Win32 project, I've got several variables which need to be modified in multiple places.  For instance, one such variable was in the WndProc function and also in a dialog procedure function.  Due to the way it was used, I was able to simply use the actual values in WndProc, and then call the dialog box using DialogBoxParam, and pass the value to the dialog box through the lParam value.

However, there are other values, such as certain bitmaps that I use for drawing or variables that are used in multiple different window message calls, where the value(s) need to be retained throughout multiple instances of the WndProc function or multiple functions.  I can control the parameters of the functions I created, but what if I need to pass a variable into the WndProc function so that I can use it regardless of multiple different window messages?  What if I need to pass in multiple values?

So far I've just been making everything global, and it works, but it feels sloppy to me...but I know that some variables are generally global as a matter of convention - like the main window and instance variables.

What do you all think?

Comment: Yes: global variables are "bad".  And yes, in classic Win32/C programming, global variables are often more or less unavoidable.  Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global variables you can store window-specific data in a C++ object associated with the relevant window.

To associate a C++ object with a window, use any of a number of existing C++ class frameworks (such as e.g. Microsoft’ [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) or Torjo's [Win32GUI](http://www.torjo.com/win32gui/index.html)), or do it yourself by using [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

For the Do It Yourself™ solution, I presented **[a complete C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306694/pass-non-static-member-without-externally-setting-it/15307484#15307484)** in another SO answer.

That said, for a tiny little program global variables + a dialog is the easiest and presents no problems. So in general, use the Right Tool™ for the job. For larger jobs, use more heavy tooling…

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you had a specific example in code.  But I think you're talking about lifetime--you have a resource (say a bitmap) and you need to reference it many times in response to different Windows messages.  You could make it global, yes, but I agree that's sloppy.

So who created the window?  Likely your "App" class or something along those lines.  Since that class's lifetime is logically longer than the window's, it could hold the resources required by the window.

Or a better approach is to create a "`Window`" class.  Your `App` instantiates a `Window` object.  The `Window` object creates the Win32 window and holds the HWND (you've now abstracted that away from the `App` so it doesn't need to know those gory details), and the `Window` instance can hold the bitmap resources.